# When execute the test script in appium it display AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: appium-android, python-appium, desiredcapabilities

```
import time
import ScrollUtil

from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.samsung.android.dialer'
desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.samsung.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity'

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
ScrollUtil.swipeUp(4,driver)
ScrollUtil.swipeDown(4,driver)
# driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator(
#     'new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains("Akash").instance(0))').click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

`
When I execute the above scripts I receive the below error messages and cannot be executed. I have already open the Appium Server

self.capabilities = response.get('value')
AttributeError: can't set attribute
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTjtO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Appium-Python-Client using pip, instead of npm
And make sure selenium 3.XX version is installed